# How do I add a directory to C header include path?

Tags: c, macos

I am having trouble installing a dependency for a program that itself depends on pcre.h.  I have this installed to /opt/local/include, but the C compiler does not see it and thus gives me:

> error: pcre.h: No such file or directory

I have confirmed this by writing a hello world program that tries to include it:

```
#include <pcre.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This also gives the error unless I specify the path as `</opt/local/include/pcre.h>`.

I would like the C compiler to find this by default but I do not know where this is configured.  Tab completion hasn't revealed any `HEADER_PATH` environment variables and I cannot find anything like it that isn't specific to *XCode*.  I am, however, using Mac OSX Snow Leopard on the off chance that makes a difference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `-I /opt/local/include` on the command line or `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include` in the environment.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `pcre-config` utility to get the right flags:

```
$ pcre-config --libs --cflags
-L/opt/local/lib -lpcre
-I/opt/local/include
```

If you're compiling via the command line,

```
$ gcc -Wall -g `pcre-config --libs --cflags` main.c
```