# #include path in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a directory to C header include path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825652/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-c-header-include-path)

I would like to set an include path for my `mysql.h` file which is located in another location, such as: `"root/a/b/c"`.

I've tried:

```
#include "/a/b/c/mysql.h"
```

But it doesn't compile. Am I missing an option?

Comment: compiler is c.   I do   " cc test.c ""

Comment: c file resides in somewhere like  "   /  d/e/f/g  "

Comment: so, root is the common super directory with mysql.h  file .

Comment: `cc` most likely indicates you're using the GNU compiler. Try `#include <mysql.h>`, and compile with `cc -o test test.c -I"/a/b/c"`.

Comment: It's been my experience that if your .h file is in a different directory you need to put angle brackets (<>) around the base name of the .h file (e.g. <mysql.h>) and then tell the compiler where to find the include file.  As another comment implied, how to do this will depend on your compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.c` file, you can use relative path to include the `.h` file. For example, if `.c` file is in `/d/e/f/g` folder and `.h` file is in `/a/b/c` folder, then your `#include` statement has to be

```
#include "../../../../a/b/c/mysql.h"
```

This is acceptable if the number of slashes is around 1 or 2 (2 is a bit dirty already). And it is not good if you move the folders around later.

Alternatively, you can only specify the name of the `.h` file, and use `-I <dir>` flag where you replace `<dir>` with the path to the folder that has `.h` file. If you move the folders around, you can just change a bit in the the compilation command (usually in a makefile).