# Change gcc include path globally

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, include, include-path

So, I'm trying to compile Ardour, on my 64-bit Mac (OS X 10.8.5), but it can't find some header files.  The header files are located in `/opt/local/include`, which doesn't show up in gcc's list of search paths, as returned by `gcc -x c++ -v -E /dev/null`.

I've read [How do I add a directory to C header include path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825652/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-c-header-include-path), and tried setting `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include`, but nothing's changed - gcc still doesn't list it as an include path.  (I also tried `CPP_INCLUDE_PATH`, just in case - no dice.)  I can't (reasonably) add a command line option to specifically include that directory, since the project uses a config script.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a default include path for gcc in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically for C++ it should be:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include 
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

You can also set that in your .bash_profile for future use.