# Including a .h file in a portable ZIPPED folder

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, include-path

I have a question.

My current project has a header I include at the beginning. I include it like so:

```
#include <C:/Data/Programming/Project_2018/Files/header.h>
```

This is proving to be a problem as I can't make it portable to another computer. My question is, can I make some sort of change to the #include in order to force the compiler to seek this header.h in the same folder as the c file that uses it?

```
#include <.../Files/header.h>
```

With ... representing the folder where the main.c file is contained?

The final destination for this project is a zip folder which is to be delivered to be used on any computer, so I need this portability...

Any clues?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use relative includes in C. If you're compiling from the directory with `main.c` in it, `#include "header.h"` will work for you. Note the double quotes, which tell the compiler to look in the source tree, not the include path.

If your directory structure is something like this:

```
.../files/
.../files/main.c
.../files/include/header.h
```

then you'll want to `#include "include/header.h"`. You can also move up the tree, so with

```
.../files/src/main.c
.../files/include/header.h
```

you can `#include "../include/header.h"`. The path is unix-y, and in unix land, `..` is the parent directory.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825652/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-c-header-include-path) might also be relevant.